# Python How do i set a variable to make its value inserted by the user?

Tags: python

```
a = (math.ceil(6*random.random()))    
b = (math.ceil(6*random.random()))   
c = (math.ceil(6*random.random()))    
CD = (10)    
e = (a+b+c)    
print ("a = {0}" .format (a))    
print ("b = {0}" .format (b))    
print ("c = {0}" .format (c))    
print ("a+b+c = {0}" .format (e))    
if a+b+c > CD:    
    print ("Maior que {0}" .format(CD))    
else:
    print ("Menor que {0}" .format(CD))
```

I want to allow the user to change the variable CD. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for python 3.x:

```
CD = float(input("Enter a number: "))
```

For python 2.x:

```
CD = float(raw_input("Enter a number: "))
```

Comment: or `float(raw_input("Enter a number: "))` if in Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

```
CD = int(raw_input())
```

The raw_input() function returns a string to the CD no matter if you enter a int, float, boolean or string in the console ,As your work was related to arithmetic operations so i converted it to float , But sure you can also use

```
CD = float(raw_input())
```

if you are trying to enter a float value , However if you are explicitly defining the type of raw_input() function as  or  then if you enter alphabetic characters as input in console then It will raise an error :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `input()` function:

```
CD = int(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful:

*If you are using python 3.x*

```
CD = float(input("Enter your number: ")) # or any other data type
```

*If you are using python 2.x*

```
CD = float(raw_input("Enter a number: ")) # or any other data type
```